# Leaflet-> prototype geometry

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geometry

I have a series of circles and lines representing some information about a geographical location. Is it possible to reuse that (complex) geometry by simply attaching it to a single point?

In other words, I would like to use that set (of geometries) as a prototype geometry for other locations, is that possible?

[image: series of circles + a polyline as an example]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "prototype geometry"? Can you give an example?

Comment: I mean a series of geometries (circles, lines, polygons) ensembled together in a layer group to graphically represent a feature.

Comment: Like a glyph? You might want to use `L.Marker`s for those.

Comment: No, it is not like glyph. I use L.circle multiple times. And then I group those circles. And I repeat this process for different points. So, I search for a solution where those group of circles could be called to assign a different geographical coordinate.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or diagram of how these work? I find it difficult to understand what you exactly mean.

Comment: I added an image. Thank you for your energy though.

Comment: And how does that look on the map? I don't have a clear idea of what your goal is.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, yes it is easy to re-use something complex with...functional abstraction !

This would look like :

```
function createMyComplexThingAt(lat, lon) {
    // a circle centered where you asked the complex thing
    var circle1 = L.circle([lat, lon], 8);
    // a circle which is on the top left
    var circle2 = L.circle([lat + 0.02, lon + 0.05], 8);
    // etc...
    // until
    var lgroup = L.layerGroup([circle1, circle2]);

    return lgroup;
}

var lgroup1 = createMyComplexThingAt(30, 44);
var lgroup2 = createMyComplexThingAt(21, 2);
var lgroup3 = createMyComplexThingAt(0.33, 5.44);
```

You can even give more parameters to your complex thing as a title text that would be used in popup or whatever you can think of.